# Algorithm to determine all possible ways a group of values can be removed from a sequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics, set-theory

I'm trying to determine how many different ways I can remove a group of values from a sequence, leaving the original sequence in order (stable), and making sure to remove only 1 instance value each from the original sequence. For example, if I had 
`[1,2,1,3,1,4,4]` and I want to remove `[1,4,4]` my resulting combinations would be:

`[1,2,1,3,1,4,4] \ [1,4,4] = [ [2,1,3,1], [1,2,3,1], [1,2,1,3] ]`

or 
`[1,2,1,3,1,4,4] \ [1,1] = [ [2,3,1,4,4], [1,2,3,4,4], [2,1,3,4,4] ]`

I have javascript code I wrote to generate combinations of all array values without removal and the removal part seems like it should be easy but I'm not seeing the algorithm when needing to potentially remove multiple values multiple times.

Comment: Should [1,2,1,3,1,4,4] \ [1,4,4] and [1,2,1,3,1,4,4] \ [4,4,1] produce identical results, provided we ignore the _order_ of the results?

Answer (score 30):

*(Because it was unclear in the original version of the question whether you meant to remove a subsequence or an unordered list, I've updated my answer to address both cases.)*

**1. Removing a sub-sequence in order**

We get a sequence of values, e.g. `[1,5,1,3,4,2,3,2,1,3,1,2]`, and a sub-sequence of values to be removed from the first sequence, e.g. `[1,3,2,1]`. If we find where every instance of the values is situated in the sequence, we get a graph like this:

[image: all connections]

Finding all ways in which the values can be removed from the sequence, in order, then means finding all ways in which the to-be-removed values in the bottom row can be connected to an instance in the sequence, without any lines crossing, e.g.:

[image: example solution]

To avoid removing values in a way which doesn't lead to a valid solution (e.g. starting by removing the right-most value 1, after which there is no value 3 that can be removed) we will first remove all the connections in the graph that lead to such invalid solutions.

This will be done by iterating over the sub-sequence twice. First we do this left-to-right, and for each value, we look at its left-most connection, and remove any connections from the value to its right which meet or cross that connection; e.g. when considering the left-most connection from the value 2, two connections from the value 1 on its right (indicated in red) are removed because they cross this connection:

[image: removing crossed connections ltr]

In the next step we go from right to left, and for each value, we look at its right-most connection, and remove any connections from the value on its left which meet or cross that connection; e.g. when considering the right-most connection from the value 1 on the right, the right-most connection from the value 2 on its left (indicated in red) is removed because it crosses this connection:

[image: removing crossed connections rtl]

We then end up with the simplified graph shown below. The combinations are then made by combining every connected instance of each value in the sub-sequence, using e.g. recursion: you iterate over the options for the first value in the sub-sequence, and each time recurse with the rest of the sub-sequence, so that the option for the first value is combined with all the options for the other values.

[image: simplified graph]

There can be crossed connections in the simplified graph, but these are no longer problematic. In the example you'll see that even if the right connection is chosen for the value 3, there is a connection for the value 2 which doesn't cross with it:

[image: example solution in simplified graph]

Turning this into code is relatively straightforward; below the code snippet you will find a run-through of the code with the data from the example.

```js
function removeSubSeq(seq, sub) {
    var posi = []; // list position of values in seq, then connect to positions in sub
    sub.forEach(function(elem) {posi[elem] = []});
    seq.forEach(function(elem, index) {if (posi[elem]) posi[elem].push(index)});
    var conn = sub.map(function(elem) {return posi[elem].slice()});

    for (var i = 1; i < conn.length; i++) {
        var left = conn[i - 1][0];
        while (conn[i][0] <= left) {
            conn[i].shift();                // remove crossed connection left-to-right
        }
    }
    for (var i = conn.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        var right = conn[i + 1][conn[i + 1].length - 1];
        while (conn[i][conn[i].length - 1] >= right) {
            conn[i].pop();                  // remove crossed connection right-to-left
        }
    }
    var combinations = [], result = [];
    combine(0, -1, []);                     // initiate recursion to find combinations
    for (var i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
        result[i] = seq.slice();            // create copies of seq and remove values
        for (var j = combinations[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            result[i].splice(combinations[i][j], 1);
        }
    }
    return result;

    function combine(step, prev, comb) {    // generate combinations using recursion
        for (var i = 0; i < conn[step].length; i++) {
            var curr = conn[step][i];
            if (prev >= curr) continue;     // skip crossed connection
            if (step + 1 == conn.length) combinations.push(comb.concat([curr]));
            else combine(step + 1, curr, comb.concat([curr]));
        }
    }
}
var result = removeSubSeq([1,5,1,3,4,2,3,2,1,3,1,2], [1,3,2,1]);
for (var i in result) document.write(result[i] + "<br>");
```

The code performs these steps:

- Create an associative array of the position of instances of each value present in sub:

```
posi[1] = [0,2,8,10], posi[2] = [5,7,11], posi[3] = [3,6,9]}
```

- Create a 2D array which links the positions in the sub-sequence to those in the sequence:

```
conn = [[0,2,8,10],[3,6,9],[5,7,11],[0,2,8,10]]
```

- Go over the array left-to-right and remove crossed connections:

```
conn = [[0,2,8,10],[3,6,9],[5,7,11],[8,10]]
```

- Go over the array right-to-left and remove crossed connections:

```
conn = [[0,2],[3,6],[5,7],[8,10]]
```

- Generate all combinations of the positions using recursion:

```
combinations = [[0,3,5,8],[0,3,5,10],[0,3,7,8],[0,3,7,10],
                [0,6,7,8],[0,6,7,10],[2,3,5,8],[2,3,5,10],
                [2,3,7,8],[2,3,7,10],[2,6,7,8],[2,6,7,10]]
```

- Use the combinations to remove the values from copies of the sequence (see Code Snippet output).

---

**2. Removing an unordered list of values**

If the list of values to be removed is not necessarily a sub-sequence of the main sequence, and the values can be removed in any order, the same method as above can be used, with a relaxation of the crossed connection rules:

> Removing crossed connections from the position list, and avoiding crossed connections when generating the combinations, only has to be done for identical values.

In this example, only the crossed connections for the duplicate values 1 are removed; first left-to-right:

[image: removing crossed connections ltr]

and then right-to-left:

[image: removing crossed connections rtl]

resulting in this simplified graph, with the problematic crossed connections for value 1 removed, and the crossed connections for values 2 and 3 remaining:

[image: simplified graph]

Below is a code example adapted from the version for sub-sequences; only a few lines in the code are changed, as indicated with comments (and I also used a different method to remove the values from the sequence). The list of values to-be-removed is sorted at the start, so that identical values are grouped together, to make it easy to keep track of identical values.

```js
function removeSubList(seq, sub) {
    sub.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});       /* SORT SUB-LIST FIRST */
    var posi = []; // list position of values in seq, then connect to positions in sub
    sub.forEach(function(elem) {posi[elem] = []});
    seq.forEach(function(elem, index) {if (posi[elem]) posi[elem].push(index)});
    var conn = sub.map(function(elem) {return posi[elem].slice()});

    for (var i = 1; i < conn.length; i++) {
        if (sub[i - 1] != sub[i]) continue;        /* SKIP FOR NON-IDENTICAL VALUES */
        var left = conn[i - 1][0];
        while (conn[i][0] <= left) {
            conn[i].shift();                // remove crossed connection left-to-right
        }
    }
    for (var i = conn.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (sub[i] != sub[i + 1]) continue;        /* SKIP FOR NON-IDENTICAL VALUES */
        var right = conn[i + 1][conn[i + 1].length - 1];
        while (conn[i][conn[i].length - 1] >= right) {
            conn[i].pop();                  // remove crossed connection right-to-left
        }
    }
    var combinations = [], result = [];
    combine(0, -1, []);                     // initiate recursion to find combinations
    for (var i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
        var s = seq.slice();                // create copy of seq and delete values
        combinations[i].forEach(function(elem) {delete s[elem]});
        result[i] = s.filter(function(elem) {return elem != undefined});
    }
    return result;

    function combine(step, prev, comb) {    // generate combinations using recursion
        for (var i = 0; i < conn[step].length; i++) {
            var curr = conn[step][i];
            if (prev >= curr && seq[prev] == seq[curr]) continue;   /* SKIP FOR NIV */
            if (step + 1 == conn.length) combinations.push(comb.concat([curr]));
            else combine(step + 1, curr, comb.concat([curr]));
        }
    }
}
var result = removeSubList([1,5,1,3,4,2,3,2,1,3,1,2], [1,3,1,2,1]);
for (var i in result) document.write(result[i] + "<br>");
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. I'm stepping through the code at the moment to figure out why removeSubSeq([8,6,4,4], [6,4,8]) returns [] instead of [ [4] ]. I might be able to work around it by using [8, 6, 4] instead.

Comment: @bkaid See the discussion I had last week with גלעד ברקן under his answer; we weren't sure whether the values had to be removed in-order, and you never answered his question about it. (But the term "subsequence" suggests it does, because 6,4,8 is not a subsequence of 8,6,4,4)

Comment: @bkaid I've adapted the method so that `[8,6,4,4] / [6,4,8]` returns `[[4]]` if you want it to. It's not much different, only 4 lines of code needed to be changed. (In fact it returns `[[4][4]]`, because there are two options to remove the 4.)

Comment: Very nice. In the solution for the first case, you've essentially found a way to efficiently generate only the sorted elements of the cartesian product of sequences.

Comment: [1 2 1 1 4 4 3 8 6 4 1 1 4 3 2 1] \ [1 1 4 1 1 1 3 4 8 6 2 2 4] ? :-)

Comment: @Stormwind I get the correct output for all your test cases, but with some duplicates (which I think are logical; there are after all 2 ways to remove [1] from [1,1]).

Comment: Fair enuff. And good, because then we know both have coded it right!

Comment: This works really well; twice as fast than the multiset recursion I came up with. I think it also very efficiently solves the all subsequences removal (akin to ordered removal combinations, that heenenee asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060558/how-can-i-determine-all-possible-ways-a-subsequence-can-be-removed-from-a-sequen).

Comment: @גלעדברקן I was going to address your question about 100 and 1000 ones. You'd have to remove 10,000 of the 100,000 connections; if you're using the algorithm for this size of input, it's probably best not to use shift() and pop(); I'd recommend using a `first` and `last` index/pointer instead of changing the array each time.

Comment: @m69 yea, I logged the iterations for it. I still don't understand why it's faster than the naive multiset I tried.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I'm working on a code version for the unordered list that doesn't sort the sublist; I think it will increase efficiency further. In the 1000/100 example, you're removing the last 100 connections, then the first and the 99 last, then the 2 first and the 98 last, and so on... you don't even have to compare anything.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Hm, the non-sorting version turned out to be 20% slower; I'll think I'll leave the code as it is :-)

Comment: I think the generic multi-set index unordered-combination algorithm is optimal for which no sorting is needed; the speed might be a question of implementation.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with simple combinatorics.

For simplicity, let's say values in original list are `1,2,3,...,n`. 

Let `a[i]` be the number of occurances of `i` in the original list.

Let `b[i]` be the number of occurances of `i` in the list of value removals

The number of options to reduce `i` is `Choose(a[i],b[i]) = a[i]!/((a[i]-b[i])!b[i]!)`

Since you combine all of these in "AND" closure, the total number of possibilities is:

```
Choose(a[1],b[1]) * Choose(a[2],b[2]) * ... * Choose(a[n], b[n])
```

Regarding values that are not in the reduction set, you don't need to worry about them. since their value in `b` list will be 0, and `Choose(x,0) = 1` for all `x`

---

This leaves you with linear time solution (assuming you can calculate Choose(.,.) in constant time after doing some preprocessing to cache factorial values.

---

In your example you have:

```
a = [3, 1, 1, 2]
b = [1, 0, 0, 2]
Choose(3,1) = 3
Choose(1,0) = 1
Choose(1,0) = 1
Choose(2,2) = 1
#number_possibilities = 3 * 1 * 1 * 1 = 3
```

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense for determining the number of possible combinations.  I'm actually trying to determine what each of the combinations are, not how many there are.  I'll play around with this to see if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

(Please also see my two other answers below, for both ordered and unordered multi-set combinations.)

To avoid "dead ends" in a recursion, create combinations from hashed indexes. For example,

```
[1,2,1,3,1,4,4] / [1,3] 

Hash = {1: [0,2,4], 3: [3]} // for repeated elements in the to-be-removed array,
                            // you could reserve the first element of the index array


Use the multi-set combination algorithm of your choice to make combinations from the 
hashed indexes, like [0,3], [2,3], etc.; and accumulate results without the corresponding elements.
```

Comment: You could remove position 4 before generating the combinations, because the last (and only) occurence of the following element is at position 3. Avoiding the dead ends is probably easier this way than in the method I suggested. Still, with [0,2,4] and [1,3,5], it would be more complicated.

Comment: I don't see why it would be complicated; please explain. Also, I don't understand your suggestion of removing position 4. All I'm doing is creating unique combinations from the possibilities of the to-be-removed list, which seems to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I mean that you can never use the 1 at position 4, because there's no 3 after it; and you can already tell once you've listed the indexes [0,2,4][3], so you can simplify them to [0,2][3] before generating the combinations. Catching that would be harder in my method. (And you're right, [0,2,4][1,3,5] isn't more complicated.)

Comment: @m69 oh, do you think OP meant the removal list is in order? The question doesn't seem to mention that.

Comment: It's not clear, but it seemed too easy otherwise :-) The whole question is rather confusing; it also mentions removing "only one instance". The first answer, which calculates how many possibilities there are, actually answers the question as it is worded.

Comment: I'll try to make it more clear, but the original array needs it needs to remain in their original order (that's what I meant by stable).

Comment: @bkaid when I said "in order," in my comment, I was referring to the to-be-removed array order. My answer allows for "stable" combinations from the original array, but assumes that elements from the to-be-removed array can be chosen in any order. For example, [1,2,1,3,4] and [1,2] as the to-be-removed list would result in removing elements indexed at [0,1] and [1,2]. Is that a correct understanding?

Answer (score 3):

To determine all the ways a group of values (let's call this group `needles`) can be removed from a sequence (called `haystack`) do the following:

1. Count how many times you have to remove each `needle` (let's call this count `k`).  This can be determined by a single pass over the `needles`.
2. Find all locations of each `needle` to be removed in the `haystack`.  This can be determined by a single pass over the `haystack`.
3. Generate all possible ways that you can remove each individual `needle` `k` times from the locations found. This is a standard [enumeration of *k*-combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Enumerating_k-combinations) and its time complexity is non-polynomial.
4. Generate all possible ways you can combine each individual `needle`'s removal possibilities together.  This is a standard [*n*-fold Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and its time complexity is also non-polynomial.
5. For each way found, filter out the relevant elements from the `haystack`.

The following is an ECMAScript 2016 implementation of this approach:

```js
function* removalCombinations(haystack, needles) {
  // Comments walk through sample input of haystack = [1,2,1,3,1,4,4] and needles = [1,4,4]

  // How many of each needle there are, e.g.,
  // needleCounts = { 1 => 1, 4 => 2 }
  let needleCounts = elementCounts(needles);

  // Where each needle is located, e.g.,
  // needleIndexes = { 1 => [ 0, 2, 4 ], 4 => [ 5, 6 ] }
  let needleIndexes = findIndices(needleCounts.keys(), haystack.entries());

  // The possible indices to be removed for a particular needle, e.g.,
  // indexCombinations = [ [ [ 0 ], [ 2 ], [ 4 ] ], [ [ 5, 6 ] ] ]
  var indexCombinations = [];
  for (let [needle, indexes] of needleIndexes) {
    indexCombinations.push(Array.from(generateCombinations(indexes, needleCounts.get(needle))));
  }

  // All the ways that the possible index removals can be fully combined together, e.g.,
  // fullRemovalCombinations = [ [ 0, 5, 6 ], [ 2, 5, 6 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
  let fullRemovalCombinations = cartesianProductOf(indexCombinations);

  // For every possible index removal combination,
  // filter those indices from the original haystack, e.g.,
  // yielded values = [ [ 2, 1, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 1, 3 ] ]
  for (let indicesToFilter of fullRemovalCombinations) {
    indicesToFilter = new Set(indicesToFilter);
    yield haystack.filter((_, index) => !indicesToFilter.has(index))
  }

  // Calculates how many there are of each element.
  function elementCounts(iterable) {
    let counts = new Map();
    for (let el of iterable) {
      counts.set(el, counts.get(el) + 1 || 1);
    }
    return counts;
  }

  // Finds the indices of where each target occurs within iterable.
  function findIndices(targets, entries) {
    let indices = new Map();
    for (let el of targets) {
      indices.set(el, []);
    }
    for (let [index, value] of entries) {
      if (indices.has(value)) {
        indices.get(value).push(index);
      }
    }
    return indices;
  }

  // Generates all possible combinations of choosing k elements from arr.
  function* generateCombinations(arr, k) {
    function* doGenerateCombinations(offset, combo) {
      if (combo.length == k) {
        yield combo;
      } else {
        let len = arr.length;
        for (let i = offset; i < len; i++) {
          yield * doGenerateCombinations(i + 1, combo.concat(arr[i]));
        }
      }
    }

    yield* doGenerateCombinations(0, []);
  }

  // Given an array of arrays, generates all ways the elements can be combined together,
  // when taking a single element from each array.
  function* cartesianProductOf(arrays) {
    function* doCartesianProductOf(i, prod) {
      if (i == arrays.length) {
        yield prod;
      } else {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
          yield* doCartesianProductOf(i + 1, prod.concat(arrays[i][j]));
        }
      }
    }

    yield* doCartesianProductOf(0, []);
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(removalCombinations([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4], [1, 4, 4]))));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(removalCombinations([8, 6, 4, 4], [6, 4, 8]))));
```

Comment: De-duping isnt important and both lists are small.  The first one works pretty well but returns wrong value when needles aren't in same order, eg  stableRemovals([8,6,4,4], [6,4,8]) returns [  ] instead of [ [4] ]

Comment: @heenenee Please don't edit the question to fit your solution. Apparently it was about a set and not a subsequence after all, and I've been wasting my time.

Comment: Apologies @m69, I really thought that was what he meant, because they clearly aren't sets since they contain duplicate elements.  Anyways, it would be a shame to lose your excellent answer, so if you like you can post your answer to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39060558/2646526) and I'll give you some points for it.

Comment: Don't worry, it was the vagueness in the original question that ultimately caused the confusion. I've addressed both cases in my answer now (and reused the code example); they weren't so different after all.

Comment: @bkaid I updated my answer with a different approach that matches needles regardless of order.

Answer (score 3):

I think Branching and Pruning is the orthodox way of solving this problem and with much optimization possibility.
But, if you just want a simple and intuitive solution. 
Here it is.

First, find the numbers which is in the remove list.
[1,2,1,3,1,4,4][1,4,4]
from this we get [1,1,1,4,4]
Second, choose as many as the remove list elements from first step, which is combination 5C3.
from this we get [1,1,1] [1,1,4] [1,4,4] ....
Third, compare the sequence. then, you get the result.
Here is the code.. Sorry it is in C++, and I used a simple combination library.

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include"combi.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> list {1,2,1,3,1,4,4};
    vector<int> to_remove {1,4,4};
    vector<int> index;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        if(find(to_remove.begin(), to_remove.end(), list[i]) != to_remove.end())
            index.push_back(i);//insert index
    }
    bool sequence;
    nCr ncr(index.size(), to_remove.size());
    while(ncr.next()) {
        sequence = true;
        for(int i=0; i<ncr.size(); i++) 
            if(list[index[ncr[i]-1]] != to_remove[i]) sequence = false;
        if(sequence) {
            for(int i=0, j=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                if(i == index[ncr[j]-1]) j++;
                else cout << list[i] << ' ';
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the combination library..

```
class Combination
{
public:
    Combination(int n, int r);
    virtual ~Combination() { delete [] ar;}
    int& operator[](unsigned i) {return ar[i];}
    bool next();
    int size() {return r;}

protected:
    int* ar;
    int n, r;
};

class nCr : public Combination
{
public: 
    nCr(int n, int r);
    bool next();
};

Combination::Combination(int n, int r)
{
    ar = new int[r];
    this->n = n;
    this->r = r;
}

nCr::nCr(int n, int r) : Combination(n, r)
{
    if(r == 0) return;
    for(int i=0; i<r-1; i++) ar[i] = i + 1;
    ar[r-1] = r-1;
}

bool nCr::next()
{
    if(r == 0) return false;
    ar[r-1]++;
    int i = r-1;
    while(ar[i] == n-r+2+i) {
        if(--i == -1) return false;
        ar[i]++;
    }
    while(i < r-1) ar[i+1] = ar[i++] + 1;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice exercise, as usual it takes 1 timeunits to code and 10 to type :-). I cannot meet the language constraint, as i use a [yet to be named language](http://www.dyalog.com), hence i may be out of the competition. But i shall challenge everyone who provided a solution with a **correctness check**. Sorry for omitting the commas. Please check with these arguments:

```
[1 2 1 3 1 4 4] \ [1 4 4 1]
```

should produce the following solutions:

```
(2 3 1)(2 1 3)(1 2 3)
```

And

```
[1 2 1 3 1 4 4] \ [1 4 4 1 1]
```

should produce the following solution:

```
(2 3)
```

And

```
[1 1 1 1 1] \ [1 1 1]
```

should (imho) produce the following solution:

```
(1 1)
```

And

```
[1] \ [2]
```

should (imho) produce the following solution:

```
[zero-length array]
```

And

```
[1 2 1 1 4 4 3 8 6 4 1 1 4 3 2 1] \ [1 1 4 1 1 1 3 4 8 6 2 2 4]
```

should produce the following solutions:

```
(4 3 1)(3 4 1)(1 4 3)(3 1 4)(4 1 3)(1 3 4)
```

***SOLUTION:***

This won't be the simplest thing to implement, though it's pretty clear logically. I'm using the term "sub-array", like this:

```
(1 2 3)(4 5 6)(7 8 9 10) <- Array with 3 "sub-arrays", 3 "elements"
```

**Step 1**: Assign the arguments (following the original example)

```
arg = 1,2,1,3,1,4,4   
vec = 1,4,4
```

**Step 2**: Check the uniques in vec, and how many of them there are.

```
A = 1,4 // The uniques in vec
B = 1,2 // Occurances of them
```

**Step 3**: Build indexes into arg for each of A (1-origin):

```
C = (1 3 5)(6 7) // 1 appears at indexes 1,3,5 in arg, 4 appears at indexes 6,7
```

**Step 4**: Take each element of C each element of B times:

```
D = (1 3 5)(6 7)(6 7) // B is (1,2) so we take (1 3 5) once and (6 7) twice.
```

**Step 5**: (The tricky step) Create all combinations of elements in D, using an outer join:

This happens by first creating all combinations of the two **rightmost** elements, ie. (6 7) and (6 7):

```
(6 6)(6 7)(7 6)(7 7) // (6 7) combined with (6 7) all possible ways
```

Then combine this with **next** D (towards **left**, that is):

```
E = (1 6 6)(1 6 7)(1 7 6)(1 7 7)(3 6 6)(3 6 7)(3 7 6)(3 7 7)(5 6 6)(5 6 7)(5 7 6)(5 7 7) // (1 3 5) combined with (6 6)(6 7)(7 6)(7 7) all possible ways
```

If there were more elements in D, we'd take them one by one (towards left) and combine with the achieved combinations so far. Until all elements of D are done (where "element" is a "sub-array").

**Step 6**: Remove such elements from E that contain duplicate numbers "inside" (eg. element (1 6 6) shall be removed):

```
F = (1 6 7)(1 7 6)(3 6 7)(3 7 6)(5 6 7)(5 7 6) // What is left from E
```

**Step 7**: Remove from F, when sub-arrays are sorted internally, such elements that are duplicates:

```
(1 6 7)(1 6 7)(3 6 7)(3 6 7)(5 6 7)(5 6 7) // F with sub-arrays sorted internally
G = (1 6 7)(3 6 7)(5 6 7)                  // Duplicate sub-arrays removed
```

**Step 8**: Almost ready! What we have now are the "non-indexes" into arg - those indexes that shall be excluded.

arg has 7 elements, hence all indexes into it are (1,2,3,4,5,6,7).

Picking the first element of G above, (1 6 7), means that indexes (1 2 3 4 5 6 7) **without** (1 6 7) is the first answer. All answers/indexes:

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) without (1 6 7) -> (2 3 4 5). arg[2 3 4 5] is (2 1 3 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) without (3 6 7) -> (1 2 4 5). arg[1 2 4 5] is (1 2 3 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) without (5 6 7) -> (1 2 3 4). arg[1 2 3 4] is (1 2 1 3)
```

Hence the answers are

```
(2 1 3 1)(1 2 3 1)(1 2 1 3)
```

**Step 9**: (Optional) The answer may contain duplicates at element level. Preserve only the uniques.

You can try this Dyalog APL one-liner at [tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org/):

```
1 2 1 3 1 4 4 {↑∪{c[b~⍵]}¨{(∊⍵≡¨∪¨⍵)/⍵},⊃∘.,/(+/¨a=¨⊂⍵)/((a←∪⍵)=¨⊂⍺)/¨⊂b←⍳⍴c←⍺} 1 4 4
```

Paste and press [enter], you get:

```
2 1 3 1
1 2 3 1
1 2 1 3
```

You won't be able to test the very longest challenged sample above, as it exceeds the tryapl server's available processing time allocation, but feel free to test with any shorter arguments.

Comment: How do you even type that stuff? Does the language come with a proprietary keyboard? Is that why there are no commas in the examples?

Comment: Btw, made any headway with the square-tiling puzzle? Someone posted a working solution using freely available libraries.

Comment: @m69, lol. They com together with CTRL. You learn them over time, so it's not a huge issue. Correct partially, the language is the reason for missing commas, not that comma would not exist, but simply because space and comma do the same job. I could type commas and the language would take them, but it _outputs_ without commas, so i don't bother either :-) plus it's a bit risky to start typing between values. As you must have guessed, all numbers in the text above are over copy/paste.

Comment: Puzzle problem is so overwhelming, so i haven't yet attacked it. It is not forgotten, but, but... heh. I'll take a look at the new solution. It's seasier to attack something when you know that there is a start and an end :-). That puzzle may be a long-runner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses a reiterating function to reduce the values in steps. This function will not return solutions if not all values of the values that need removed are present in the starting array.

```
// Algorithm to strip values from an array
// Note, if not all elements of the stripValues array are found this function will return no solutions

function stripValues(startingValues, stripValues) {
    let solutions = []

    searchForSolutions(startingValues, stripValues, solutions, [])

    return solutions
}

function searchForSolutions(startingValues, stripValues, solvedSolutions, possibleSolution) {
    // If there are values to remove
    if(stripValues.length > 0) {
        // Copy the values of any possible solution to avoid tampering
        let newPossibleSolution = []
        possibleSolution.forEach((value) => {
            newPossibleSolution.push(value)
        })

        // Loop through the starting values looking for an instance of the first remaining value to strip
        for(i = 0; i < startingValues.length; i++) {
            if(startingValues[i] == stripValues[0]) {
                // The value was found, so reduce the arrays and look for the next element to remove
                let remainingStripValues = []
                stripValues.forEach((value, index) => {
                    if(index > 0) {
                        remainingStripValues.push(value)
                    }
                })

                let remainingValues = []
                for(j = i + 1; j< startingValues.length; j++) {
                    remainingValues.push(startingValues[j])
                }

                // Reiterate the search
                searchForSolutions(remainingValues, remainingStripValues, solvedSolutions, newPossibleSolution)
            }

            // Whether or not the value was found we want to continue finding permutations 
            newPossibleSolution.push(startingValues[i])
        }
    } else {
        //There are no remaining values to search for, so we have found a solution
        for(i = 0; i < startingValues.length; i++) {
            newPossibleSolution.push(startingValues[i]);
        }

        solvedSolutions.push(newPossibleSolution)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is also available here: [How can I determine all possible ways a subsequence can be removed from a sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060558/how-can-i-determine-all-possible-ways-a-subsequence-can-be-removed-from-a-sequen/39070282#39070282))

This is an answer for ordered multi-set combinations, which seems akin to enumerating matching subsequences in the larger array.

First, order your set to be removed in the same order of appearance as in the main array (`O(n)` time with hash), then proceed with the algorithm below.

This problem can be solved in `O(n*m + r)` time, where `r` is the total length of the results, using the classic [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm.

Once the table is made, as in Wikipedia's [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Traceback_approach), replace it with a list of the cells with a diagonal arrow that also have a value corresponding with their row. Now traverse backwards from each cell with a diagonal in the last row, accumulating the relevant index in the string and duplicating and splitting the accumulation such that each cell with a diagonal arrow will have a continuation to all cells with a diagonal in the preceding row that are to the left of it (store that count as well, as you build the matrix) and one less in value. When an accumulation reaches a zero cell, splice the accumulated indexes from the string and add that as a result.

(The arrows correspond with whether the LCS so far came from `LCS(X[i-1],Y[j]) and/or LCS(X[i],Y[j-1]), or LCS(X[i-1],Y[j-1])`, see the function [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#LCS_function_defined).)

For example:

```
  0  a  g  b  a  b  c  c
0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
a 0 ↖1  1  1 ↖1  1  1  1
b 0  1  1 ↖2  2 ↖2  2  2
c 0  1  1  2  2  2 ↖3 ↖3
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function remove(arr,sub){
  var _arr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(v,i){ if (!sub.has(i)) _arr.push(arr[i]); });
  return _arr;
}

function f(arr,sub){
  var res = [],
      lcs = new Array(sub.length + 1),
      nodes = new Array(sub.length + 1);
     
  for (var i=0; i<sub.length+1;i++){
    nodes[i] = [];
    lcs[i] = [];
   
    for (var j=0; j<(i==0?arr.length+1:1); j++){
      // store lcs and node count on the left
      lcs[i][j] = [0,0];
    }
  }
 
  for (var i=1; i<sub.length+1;i++){ 
    for (var j=1; j<arr.length+1; j++){
      if (sub[i-1] == arr[j-1]){
        lcs[i][j] = [1 + lcs[i-1][j-1][0],lcs[i][j-1][1]];
       
        if (lcs[i][j][0] == i){
                  // [arr index, left node count above]
          nodes[i].push([j - 1,lcs[i-1][j-1][1]]);
       
          lcs[i][j][1] += 1;
        }
       
      } else {
        lcs[i][j] = [Math.max(lcs[i-1][j][0],lcs[i][j-1][0]),lcs[i][j-1][1]];
      }
    }
  }
   
  function enumerate(node,i,accum){
    if (i == 0){
      res.push(remove(arr,new Set(accum)));
      return;
    }
    
    for (var j=0; j<node[1]; j++){
      var _accum = accum.slice();
      _accum.push(nodes[i][j][0]);
      
      enumerate(nodes[i][j],i - 1,_accum);
    }
  }
  
  nodes[sub.length].forEach(function(v,i){ 
    enumerate(nodes[sub.length][i],sub.length - 1,[nodes[sub.length][i][0]]); 
  });

  return res;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,2,1,3,1,4,4], [1,4,4])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([8,6,4,4], [6,4,8])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,1,2], [1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['a','g','b','a','b','c','c'], ['a','b','c'])));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to enumerate unordered combinations of a multi-set of elements, you can do exactly that:

Record the positions in the array of the elements in the multi-set; enumerate all combinations of `choose(indexes,multiplicity)`.

JavaScript code:

```js
// straighforward choose(n,r) combinations
function choose(ns,r){
  if (r > ns.length) return [];
    
  var res = [];

  function _choose(i,_res){
    if (_res.length == r){
      res.push(_res);
      return;

    } else if (_res.length + ns.length - i == r){
      _res = _res.concat(ns.slice(i));
      res.push(_res);
      return
    }

    var temp = _res.slice();
    temp.push(ns[i]);

    _choose(i + 1,temp);
    _choose(i + 1,_res);
  }

  _choose(0,[]);
  return res;
}

// function to collect an array without specified indexes
function remove(arr,indexSet){
  var _arr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(v,i){ if (!indexSet.has(i)) _arr.push(arr[i]); });
  return _arr;
}

// main function
// the multiset is formatted as {element: [multiplicity,indexes]}
function removeAllCombs(arr,multiset){
  var res = [];
  
  // record the positions of multiset elements in the array
  arr.forEach(function(v,i){
    if (multiset[v]) multiset[v][1].push(i);
  });
  
  var keys = Object.keys(multiset);
  
  function enumerate(i,accum){
    if (i == keys.length){
      res.push(remove(arr,new Set(accum)));
      return;
    }
    
    var combs = choose(multiset[keys[i]][1],multiset[keys[i]][0]);

    for (let j in combs){
      var _accum = accum.slice();
      _accum = _accum.concat(combs[j]);
      
      enumerate(i + 1,_accum);
    }
  }
  
  enumerate(0,[]);
  return res;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  removeAllCombs([1,2,1,3,1,4,4],{1: [1,[]], 4: [2,[]]})
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this proposal builds a map with the wanted items to delete, count them, checks if the length of the same items is the same as in the given, then put it into the `common` array. All others are used for building a combination and later for building a cross product.

At the end, all values, found in the cross product, or in the common are filtered out.

```js
function remove(sequence, sub) {
    var count = new Map,
        distribute = [],
        common = [];

    sub.forEach((a, i) => {
        var o = count.get(a)
        if (!o) {
            o = { sub: 0, pos: [] };
            count.set(a, o);
        }
        o.sub++;
    });

    sequence.forEach((a, i) => {
        var o = count.get(a);
        o && o.pos.push(i);
    });

    count.forEach((v, k) => {
        if (v.pos.length > v.sub) {
            distribute.push({ value: k, pos: v.pos, count: v.sub });
        } else {
            common.push(k);
        }
    });

    return crossProduct(distribute.map(a => combination(a.pos, a.count))).
        map(a =>
            sequence.filter((b, i) => a.indexOf(i) === -1 && common.indexOf(b) === -1));
}

console.log(remove([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4], [1, 4, 4])); // [ [2,1,3,1], [1,2,3,1], [1,2,1,3] ]
console.log(remove([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4], [1, 1]));    // [ [2,3,1,4,4], [1,2,3,4,4], [2,1,3,4,4] ]
console.log(remove([1, 2, , 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 5], [1, 4, 4, 5]));

function crossProduct(array) {
    function c(part, index) {
        array[index].forEach(a => {
            var p = part.concat(a);
            if (p.length === array.length) {
                result.push(p);
                return;
            }
            c(p, index + 1);
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    if (array.length === 1) { return array[0]; }
    c([], 0);
    return result;
}

function combination(array, size) {

    function c(part, start) {
        var i, l, p;
        for (i = start, l = array.length + part.length + 1 - size; i < l; i++) {
            p = part.slice();
            p.push(array[i]);
            p.length < size ? c(p, i + 1) : result.push(p);
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    c([], 0);
    return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```